# Documentation or meaning of the pending_renewal_info attribute in an In-App Purchase receipt?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes, receipt-validation

Has anyone encountered the `pending_renewal_info` attribute while validating a receipt for an In-App Purchase or can anyone point to documentation regarding this field?

I have looked at the [Apple documentation for Receipt Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW12) but do not see any references to this field which our system encountered for the first time today and flagged as being an unknown field. I am looking for any information to understand what it means and what action I should take.

Comment: Apple explicitly states in the [receipt validation guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1) *"Keys not documented below are reserved for use by Apple and must be ignored by your app."*

Answer (score 3):

It is documented at
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW4

This hints whether a subscription is still pending for auto-renewal.
More details about these in WWDC 2017 Lecture 305 - Advanced StoreKit

Answer (score 0):

It is documented at [responseBody.Pending_renewal_info](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody/pending_renewal_info).

The most important info it contains IMO is `grace_period_expires_date_ms` which can be used to determine whether the subscription is in the grace period and `is_in_billing_retry_period` which determines whether Apple is trying to renew the subscription or not.

Discussion section:

> In the JSON file, pending_renewal_info is an array in which each element contains the pending renewal information for each auto-renewable subscription identified by the product_id. A pending renewal may refer to a renewal that is scheduled in the future or a renewal that failed in the past for some reason. It is only returned for app receipts that contain auto-renewable subscriptions.
>
> You can use this value to get critical information about any pending renewal transactions for an auto-renewable subscription.

Refer [Engineering Subscriptions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/705/) video from WWDC 2019 for more information.